# Google Chrome Command-Line Notice

Tags: google-chrome, unity-dash

I get this notice when i start/stop google chrome from command line.

> [18848:18924:1203/171505:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(240)]
>   PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates

However, google-chrome x64 seem to works fine

[image]

Comment: I fail to see a notice that would be in context of dash-based launch here, do you mean when you launch from the command line

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=421239

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it ain't broke, don't fix it. I get similar warnings for many programs I execute through the command line and I've never had any problems. You could just ignore those messages, since, as you say, there's no problem with chrome itself.